# Why is this code slower in Cython than in Python?

Tags: python, performance, cython

I'm starting to learn Cython because of performance issues. This particular code is an attempt to implement some new algorithms in the transportation modeling (for planning) area.

I decided to start with a very simple function that I will use a LOT (hundreds of millions of times) and would definitely benefit from a performance increase.

I implemented this function in three different ways and tested them for the same parameter (for the sake of simplicity) for 10 million times each:

- Cython code in a cython module. Running time: 3.35s
- Python code in a Cython module. Running time: 4.88s
- Python code on the main script. Running time: 2.98s

  As you can see, the cython code was 45% slower than the python code in a cython module and 64% slower than the code written on the main script. How is that possible?  Where am I making a mistake?

The cython code is this:

```
def BPR2(vol, cap, al, be):
    con=al*pow(vol/cap,be)
    return con


def func (float volume, float capacity,float alfa,float beta):
    cdef float congest
    congest=alfa*pow(volume/capacity,beta)
    return congest
```

And the script for testing is this:

```
agora=clock()
for i in range(10000000):
    q=linkdelay.BPR2(10,5,0.15,4)

agora=clock()-agora
print agora

agora=clock()
for i in range(10000000):
    q=linkdelay.func(10,5,0.15,4)
    
agora=clock()-agora
print agora

agora=clock()
for i in range(10000000):
    q=0.15*pow(10/5,4)
    
agora=clock()-agora
print agora
```

I'm aware of issues like transcendental functions (power) being slower, but I dont think it should be a problem.

Since there is an overhead for looking for the function on the function space, would it help the performance if I passed an array for the function and got an array back? Can I return an array using a function written in Cython?

For reference, I'm using:

- Windows 7 64bits
- Python 2.7.3 64 Bits
- Cython 0.16 64 Bits
- Windows Visual Studio 2008

Comment: So, if you're thinking about passing an array into the function, presumably you can vectorise the code, in which case have you considered doing what you're trying to do simply with [NumPy](http://numpy.scipy.org/)? Certainly, the function in your example can be trivially implemented on arrays using NumPy.

Comment: Well it's an extremely trivial function and cython does have to convert the `PyObject*` to a float and then back doesn't it? Seems like a lot of overhead for such a small function.

Comment: Just to clarify, your problem is that you're spending most of your time in calling the function, which doesn't get improved by using Cython. I suggest you rephrase your question without prejudicing the solution (Cython). That way those that are wont to answer will have more to work with. A small example of how you actually use the code would be useful.

Comment: Don't you need to use `double` type data instead of `float` ?

Comment: "As you can see, the cython code was 45% slower than the python code in a cython module" no, you said cython took 3.35s and python in cython took 4.88s. In my world, that's 45% faster.

Answer (score 3):

Testing was done using :

```
for i in range(10000000):
  func(2.7,2.3,2.4,i)
```

Here are the results:

```
cdef float func(float v, float c, float a, float b):
  return a * (v/c) ** b
#=> 0.85

cpdef float func(float v, float c, float a, float b):
  return a * (v/c) ** b
#=> 0.84

def func(v,c,a,b):
  return a * pow(v/c,b)
#=> 3.41

cdef float func(float v, float c, float a, float b):
  return a * pow(v/c, b)
#=> 2.35
```

For highest efficiency you need to define the function in C and make the return type static.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do the last 2 get better if you `from libc.math cimport pow` ?

Comment: I now get 3.35 and 1.35 respectively. So yes.

Comment: Surely any time reduction in setting a static return type in an external C lib is going to be dwarfed by the calling overhead. All your speed increases are just down to minimising the calls into the python libs. Also, I'm curious what cython is doing to make the `**` operator faster than `libc.math`'s `pow`. Any chance you can post the outputted C code?

Comment: I just checked. Cython is using `powf`, which I guess is faster on your machine. Incidentally, Cython already sets the return type to be static.

Comment: I replaced the pow function with ** and everything is faster by about 30%.  I also tested the loop inside the function (just looping through the same parameters recomputing the same 10 million times) and Cython is actually 3 times faster than python compiled as cython and 8 times faster than pure python in the main script...

Comment: I guess the problem was actually the overhead in caling the function too many times...

Comment: @user1480643 even using cython, you're still going to have a big overhead from calling in the python domain unless you change how you work. You need to operate on arrays that can be statically typed and reduced to simple C in order to get the most out of Cython. Seriously, try reposing your question with a broader perspective.

Comment: @Henry Gomersall,
          What do you mean by operating on arrays that can be statically typed?  I'll be working on Python most of the time (specially to take advantage of sparse matrix implementations of NumPy) so my arrays will be python arrays...

Comment: In practice, I mean numpy arrays. The point is, with a numpy array, you can write a loop in (basically) python and then see in C that it's about as tight as it would be hand coded.

Answer (score 1):

This function could be optimized as such (in both python and cython, removing the intermediate variable is faster):

```
def func(float volume, float capacity, float alfa,f loat beta):
    return alfa * pow(volume / capacity, beta)
```

Comment: That's not exactly going to lead to the desired order of magnitude speed increases...

Comment: But it will help. Try this and then see where it puts the speed.

Comment: No it won't. This is the essence of the problem with premature optimisation. Put your efforts into algorithmic improvements.

Answer (score 1):

When Cython is slower, it's probably due to type conversions, and possibly exacerbated by a lack of type annotations.  Also, if you use C datastructures in Cython, that'll tend to be faster than using Python datastructures in Cython.

I did a performance comparison between CPython 2.x (with and without Cython, with and without psyco), CPython 3.x (with and without Cython), Pypy, and Jython.  Pypy was by far the fastest, at least for the micro-benchmark examined:
http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/backshift/documentation/performance/